# org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 Forbidden [secret/test_demo]: 1 error occurred: * permission denied

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I have a springboot app that uses these versions:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

I have a bootstrap.yml with the following:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        vault:
            host: vault-cluster-demo.vault.ccff9e8b-4390-44c2-a1ec-16fb41261e45.aws.hashicorp.cloud
            port: 8200
            scheme: https
            uri: https://vault-cluster-demo.vault.ccff9e8b-4390-44c2-a1ec-16fb41261e45.aws.hashicorp.cloud:8200
            authentication: TOKEN
            token: s.ARhmynnu8rW8Jhw6iv4Rd2cM.DWjnX
            kv:
                enabled: true
                application-name: test_demo
                default-context: test_demo
                backend: secret
            generic:
                enabled: false
```

create new Engine in Secrets sections with name secret and create secret with path name test_demo.
Then set policy under Policies tab and click Create ACL policy with name test_demo.set policy

```
path "test_demo/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read", "update" ]
}
path "sys/namespaces/*" {
   capabilities = [ "create", "read", "update", "delete", "list" ]
}
```

*when I tried to access from spring boot project I am recivig an error
org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 Forbidden [secret/test_demo]: 1 error occurred:
* permission denied*

how can I solve it.Thanks

Comment: How do you authenticate to Vault (often with [AppRole](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle)) ? Are the policies attached to your token? Show us how you mounted the kv store (`vault secrets enable ....`).